# This function load the server - why?

Tags: javascript, validation

I have this function.

It's a validation for register page, need to check if the date is vaild.

For some reason, it call the server and load the page,
I thought maybe the  `date.getFullYear()` do it , but no.

Thanks

```
<script>
          function CheckDate  (sender, args)
          {
              var date = document.getElementById("DateReg").toString();

              var FirstStop = DateReg.ToString().IndexOf("/");
              var LastStop = DateReg.ToString().LastIndexOf("/");

              var day="",month="",year="";
              var DateChar = DateReg.Text.ToCharArray();

              for (var i = 0; i < FirstStop; i++)
              {
                      day += DateChar[i];
              }

          for (var i = FirstStop + 1; i < LastStop; i++)
          {
              month += DateChar[i];
          }

          for (var i = LastStop+1; i < DateChar.Length; i++)
          {
              year += DateChar[i];
          }

          var date = new Date();
          var CurrentYear = date.getFullYear();



          args.IsValid = true;

          if (day < 1 || day > 31 || month < 1 || month > 12 || year > CurrentYear || year < CurrentYear - 120)
          {
              args.IsValid = false;
          }


          return args.IsValid;
          }

    </script>
```

DateReg :

```
               <asp:TextBox ID="DateReg" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
```

Call from here

Comment: what is the html element with id="DateReg" ?

Comment: i can't see the declaration of the variable DateReg

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="DateReg" runat="server" TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>

Comment: The problem may be that you call that function from a `<form>` "submit" handler, and the handler does not prevent the default browser action of submitting the form.

Comment: No, i call it from asp:button

Comment: @NoamShamgar no, you're calling it from a `<button>` tag of some sort once the translated code makes it out to the browser, and generally the default behavior of buttons not explicitly marked as *not* being "submit" buttons is to submit the `<form>` that they're in.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
function CheckDate  (sender, args)
{
    var date = document.getElementById("DateReg").value;
    date = date.split('/');
    var day= date[0] ,month= date[1], year= date[2];

    var date = new Date();
    var CurrentYear = date.getFullYear();

    args.IsValid = true;

    if (day < 1 || day > 31 || month < 1 || month > 12 || year > CurrentYear || year < CurrentYear - 120)
    {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }

    if(args.IsValid)
        document.getElementById("IdOfYourForm").submit();
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: can you please put the code where you call this function ?